# sql query error in data_formate and datatime

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have one query in that i have to check date filtering searching and my query as follow in that `created` **is field and its contain datetime** and as per date-picker i have get "d-m-Y" formate
Please help me to solve this error

```
SELECT o.*,u.first_name,u.last_name,u.email 
FROM tbl_orders AS o 
LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS u ON o.customer_id = u.id 
WHERE 1=1 AND date_format(o.created,'%d-%m-%Y') >= "01-04-2017" 
AND date_format(o.created,'%d-%m-%Y') <= "01-05-2017" 
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0 , 25
```

i have found Zero result
please help me

Thanks

Comment: Try to change '%d-%m-%Y'..

Comment: thanks for response but still give me zero i have check both formate but :(

Comment: show sample data here

Answer (score 1):

You are using an incorrect date literal.  You should be comparing the `created` datetime column against `'2017-05-01'`.  Try this full query:

```
SELECT o.*, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email
FROM tbl_orders AS o
LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS u
    ON o.customer_id = u.id
WHERE o.created BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-05-01'
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 25
```

You don't need to use `DATE_FORMAT()` on the `created` column, assuming you correctly told us that it is datetime, because it is *already* a date type.  Also, you should generally use single, not double, quotes when writing string literals in SQL.

Please refer to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html) for more information on acceptable formats for date literals.

Answer (score 0):

Your date_format is not proper

%d  Day of month, numeric (00-31)

%m  Month, numeric (00-12)

%Y  Year, numeric, four digits

So your date format function should be

```
date_format(o.created,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: thanks but i have try this one also but its give zero resut

Answer (score 0):

Change date:

**from:**

```
AND date_format(o.created,'%y-%m-%d') >= "01-04-2017" 
AND date_format(o.created,'%y-%m-%d') <= "01-05-2017"
```

**To:**

```
AND date_format(o.created,'%y-%m-%d') >= "2017-01-04" 
AND date_format(o.created,'%y-%m-%d') <= "2017-01-05"
```

Comment: i have also check this see the following query

Comment: SELECT o.*,u.first_name,u.last_name,u.email FROM tbl_orders AS o LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS u ON o.customer_id = u.id WHERE 1=1 AND date_format(o.created,'%y-%m-%d') >= "2017-04-01" AND date_format(o.created,'%y-%m-%d') <= "2017-05-01" ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0 , 25

Answer (score 0):

return type of date_format() function  is VARCHAR. So it can't be use for compare. Use STR_TO_DATE like following

```
STR_TO_DATE(o.created, '%Y-%m-%d') <= STR_TO_DATE("01-05-2017", '%d-%m-%Y')
```